# Extract 2 pieces of information from html in python

Tags: python, html, html-table, beautifulsoup, lxml

I need help figuring out how to extract Grab and the number following data-b. There are many `<tr>` in the complete unmodified webpage and I need to filter using the "Need" just before `</a>`. I've been trying to do this with beautiful soup, though it looks like lxml might work better. I can get either all of the `<tr>`s or only the `< a>...< /a>` lines that contain Need but not just the `<tr>`s that contain need in that `<a>` line.

```html
<tr >
     <td>3</td>
     <td><a href="/local/app">Leave</a></td><td><a href="https://www.leave.com/" target="_blank">Useless</a></td>
     <td class="text-right"> <span class="float2" data-a="24608000.0" data-b="518" data-n="818">Garbage</span></td>
     <td class="text-right"> <span class="Float" data-a="3019" data-b="0.0635664" data-n="283">Garbage2</span></td>
     <td class="text-right">7.38%</td>
     <td class="text-right " >Recently</td>
</tr>

<tr >
     <td>4</td>
     <td><a href="/local">Grab</a></td><td><a href="https://grab.com" target="_blank">Need</a></td>
     <td class="text-right"> <span class="bloat2" data="22435000.0" data-b="512" data-n="74491.2">More junk</span></td>
     <td class="text-right"> <span class="bloat" data-a="301.177" data-b="35.848" data-n="0.5848">More junk2</span></td>
     <td class="text-right">Some more</td>
     <td class="text-right " >Recently</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = '''<tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td><a href="/local/app">Leave</a></td><td><a href="https://www.leave.com/" target="_blank">Useless</a></td>
 <td class="text-right"> <span class="float2" data-a="24608000.0" data-b="518" data-n="818">Garbage</span></td>
 <td class="text-right"> <span class="Float" data-a="3019" data-b="0.0635664" data-n="283">Garbage2</span></td>
 <td class="text-right">7.38%</td>
 <td class="text-right " >Recently</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>4</td>
 <td><a href="/local">Grab</a></td><td><a href="https://grab.com" target="_blank">Need</a></td>
 <td class="text-right"> <span class="bloat2" data="22435000.0" data-b="512" data-n="74491.2">More junk</span></td>
 <td class="text-right"> <span class="bloat" data-a="301.177" data-b="35.848" data-n="0.5848">More junk2</span></td>
 <td class="text-right">Some more</td>
 <td class="text-right " >Recently</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup.findAll('a',{"href":"/local" })[0].text)
for a in soup.findAll('span',{"class":["bloat","bloat2"]}):
  print(a['data-b'])
```